# Setting a var equal to SQL code

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-7

I have a school PAT project where I need to do something extra, and in order to do so I need to do the following (I am using delphi 7 and ms access):
I want to set `sql code =` to a variable in order to use the var for something like a calculation.
I am thinking something like this:

```
s(var):=ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT Birthdate where username = '+edtUsername.text;
```

So basically I want to set a specific ms access cell = to a var in delphi.

Comment: LOL Who is this?? MSC "programers"

Comment: Cause what you want is in the back of our book (P214)

Answer (score 4):

You trying to do too much in one line.

You set the `SQL.Text`
Then run the Query.
Then read one line into your variable.

Furthermore never inject parameters directly into a query; this leads to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Use parameters instead.

In pseudo code:

```
 ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT Birthdate where username = :name';
 ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('name'):= aname;   <<-- save way to use parameters.
 ADOQuery1.RunQuery;
 var1:= ADOQuery1.FieldByName('BirthDate').AsDate;
```

Obviously you need to fix the SQL statement, because it is incomplete and tweak the code a little. But I'll leave that as an exercise.

Here's the documentation for TADOQuery: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOQuery